# How To Downgrade nodejs version on termux?

Tags: node.js, termux, downgrade

How to downgrade nodejs version on termux?, my termux already isntalled with 18.3.0 nodejs version and i need to use the older version.

Answer (score -3):

You can download Node Version Manager from [here](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm). It lets you choose to install the version you want, anytime you want.

From documentation:

To install:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
```

Once it is installed:

```
nvm use 16
```

You can choose 18,16,14 or whatever you want.

Comment: You obviously never tested your solution, because there is an incompatibility between Termux and NVM, because both reserve the `PREFIX` variable with different values. https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/1645